# tinymce: invert enter and shift+enter

Tags: tinymce

when i press enter tinymce generates a paragraph + a tag br
i don't want this behaviour.
Is possible obtain with enter pressing the behaviour of pressing shift+enter ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [force_br_newlines](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:Configuration/force_br_newlines) option sounds like what you're after.